# Aggregate always 15 rows to 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table with one row for each minute with a DateTime timestamp. I need a function to return always 15 minutes aggregated.

The minute rows have the following columns:

- Open, High, Low Close, Timestamp

So if I have 60 rows for each one minute, the result should be 4 rows with:

- Open of the first minute
- High - highest of all High
- Low - lowest of all Low
- Close of the last minute
- Timestamp of the last minute

I do not have the slightest idea how this could be achievable. Can somebody point to the functions SQL provides for such a task?

Example minute rows:

| Open | High | Low | Close | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 17 | 17 | 9 | 2021-02-18-15:00:00 |
| 9 | 13 | 4 | 12 | 2021-02-18-15:01:00 |
| 12 | 21 | 11 | 17 | 2021-02-18-15:02:00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 22 | 23 | 18 | 21 | 2021-02-18-15:15:00 |

Example of the desired output row

| Open | High | Low | Close | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 23 | 4 | 22 | 2021-02-18-15:00:00 |

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Re "I do not have the slightest idea how this is possible." - this makes me really sad :(

Comment: I added some more information and example data

Comment: One period end is next period start, yes?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to ask differently. If you have record at x:15:00, then this belongs to two periods (candles), yes? And if you don't have record for x:15:00, but have for x:14:00 and x:16:00, what moment you consider for candle closing and next candle opening?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from @GordonLinoff's answer, but with numerous corrections:

```
select
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then [open] end) as [open],
       max(high) as high,
       min(low) as low,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then [close] end) as [close],
       min(timestamp) EarliestTimeStamp,
       max(timestamp) LatestTimeStamp,
       count(1) RowsSummarised
from 
    (select MyTable.*,
     row_number() over (partition by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15 order by timestamp) as seqnum_asc,
     row_number() over (partition by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15 order by timestamp desc) as seqnum_desc
      from MyTable t
     ) t
group by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15
order by min(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes -- contrary to the provided data -- that the OP really wants exactly 15 rows per group rather than 16.  That is minutes 00-14 are in one group, 15-29 in another, and so on.

You can use window functions and aggregation.  One method is:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp),
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then open end) as open,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then close end) as close,
       max(high), min(low)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15 order by timestamp) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15 order by timestamp) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by convert(date, timestamp), datepart(hour, timestamp), datepart(minute, timestamp) / 15
order by min(timestamp);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13c48eaea082376302995d70ea5a9e9e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this work, assuming that boundary recods should count in both periods? (Even if you group by 15min periods, not by every minute, which seems not correct to me?)

Comment: @Arvo . . . Although that could be what the OP intends, I suspect it is just a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thanks, that helps a lot.